# Trouble bundling JavaScript assets in Laravel Project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vite

The issue is this one:
However I've tried a lot, I'm not being able to set some JS functions in my project as global functions.

I got in 'resources\js":

numerosALetras.js:

```
///////////////////////////

function unidades_nal(n){
...
}

function decenas_nal(n){
...
}

function centenas_nal(n){
...
}

/////////////////

function numerosAMeses(n){
...
}

function numeroADias(n){
...
}

export function numeroALetras(n){
...
}

function ucwords(str){
...
}

export function letrasANumero(str){
...
}

//export default {numeroALetras,letrasANumero};
```

app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';


import { numeroALetras, letrasANumero } from './numerosALetras';
//import * as numerosALetras from './numerosALetras';

window.numeroALetras = numeroALetras;
window.letrasANumero = letrasANumero;

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import focus from '@alpinejs/focus';
window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.plugin(focus);

Alpine.start();
```

My 'vite.config.js' is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

However, I'm getting at the browser console:

> crear:1238    GET http://localhost/livewire/livewire.js?id=90730a3b0e7144480175 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

> crear:587 Uncaught ReferenceError: numeroALetras is not defined  at crear:587:3 (anonymous) @ crear:587

> crear:1244 Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined at crear:1244:27

Here's my browser output on the line `alert(numeroALetras(35));`:

[image: Here's my browser output]

I've tried both `npm run build` and `npm run dev`, but both aren't working.

Any idea of what's going wrong? Any more information needed?

I didn't include the whole content of my JS functions since I'ts a lot of code, but I can share it if needed.

Thanks a lot!
Leandro

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

I was coding the line `alert(numeroALetras(35));` outside my  `$(document).ready( ...);` function into my <script> tags at my Blade view. That's it, before the DOM was fully loaded. I've now placed it inside it, and worked fine.

So, the trouble was that that sentence was being executed BEFORE my assets defined in my application in "app.js" were loaded properly.  As a result, the function numeroALetras was not defined at that moment, leading to the   `"Uncaught TypeError: window.numeroALetras is not a function"`  error.
By moving the  `alert(numeroALetras(35));`  inside the  `$(document).ready(...)`  function, I'm ensuring that it will be executed only AFTER the DOM is fully loaded, and all the assets defined in "app.js" are properly loaded and available.